# LCD Display many numbers?

Tags: arduino-ide

There is no error in the code it already stored 11 numbers in serial print  but the problem I want to input 11 numbers only in keypad That will display 11 numbers also in LCD. But it display many numbers in LCD. Any idea please?

[image]

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(6, 5);
int table[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Wire.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //three columns

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
    { '1', '2', '3' },
    { '4', '5', '6' },
    { '7', '8', '9' },
    { '*', '0', '#' }
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = { 2, 3, 17, 16 }; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = { 15, 14, 13 }; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
int count = 0;
Keypad kpd = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
char entryStr[13]; // This can hold up to 4 digits
int i = 0;
//char n1, n2, n3;
//char buf[15]; // i put here***
char n1[11], n2[11], n3[11];
void setup()
{
    Wire.begin();
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.begin(20, 4);
    ask();
}

void loop()
{
    Wire.requestFrom(2, 3); // request 6 bytes from slave device #2 for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {

    int c = Wire.read(); // receive a byte as character
    Serial.print(c);
    table[i] = c;
    Serial.print('\t');
    // print the character } Serial.print('\n'); Serial.print(table[0]); Serial.print('\t'); Serial.print(table1); Serial.print('\t'); Serial.print(table[2]); Serial.print('\n');

    //if(table[0]<=8) //{ //Serial.print("Flame Detected!"); //Serial.println("Level1");
}
void ask()
{

    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Enter no1.:");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("(starts with 0)");
    lcd.setCursor(1, 2);
    GetNumber(n1, sizeof(n1) - 1);;

    Serial.print(n1);

    delay(1);

    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Enter no2.:");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("(starts with 0)");
    lcd.setCursor(1, 2);
    GetNumber(n2, sizeof(n2) - 1);

    Serial.println(n2);
    delay(1);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Enter no3.:");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("(starts with 0)");
    lcd.setCursor(1, 2);
    GetNumber(n3, sizeof(n3) - 1);

    Serial.println(n3);
    delay(1);
    Serial.println(n1);
    Serial.println(n2);
    Serial.println(n3);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("list of numbers ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("will be shown press");
    lcd.setCursor(1, 2);
    lcd.print("reset if wrong");

    delay(7000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Numbers Stored:");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("no1.:0");
    lcd.print(n1);
    lcd.setCursor(1, 2);
    lcd.print("no2.:0");
    lcd.print(n2);
    lcd.setCursor(2, 3);
    lcd.print("no3.:0");
    lcd.print(n3);
}
void GetNumber(char* result, const int maxLength)
{
    char key = kpd.getKey();
    int i = 0; // how far through buffer we are
    while (key != '#') {
        switch (key) {
        case NO_KEY:
            break;

        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':

            lcd.print(key);
            if (i < maxLength) {
                result[i++] = key;
                result[i] = 0; // terminating null
            }
            break;

        case '*': // backspace
            if (i > 0) {
                i--;
                result[i] = 0; // terminating null
            }

            break;
        }

        key = kpd.getKey();
    }

} // end of GetNumber
```

Comment: what i mean is The number i input in keypad is the same number iin LCD thats right.  But i want only in LCD to display 11 numbers only.

Comment: You declared `n1` to be 11-char long, which doesn't have room for 11 numbers plus the null terminator. How are you getting 11 correct numbers in the first place is probably random.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me any idea how can i fix it?

Comment: If 11 is not enough space for 11 numbers plus a null-terminator, I wonder what would be enough space?